# Equivalences of $S^n$ vs. $\Omega^nS^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $H(n)$ be the group of self-homotopy-equivalences of $S^n$ preserving the basepoint. I read that $H(n)$ may be identified with ''two components of $\Omega^nS^n$''.

What does this mean and how can I see it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maps $[S^n,S^n]$ are classified by degree.  For each $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ there is a component of $\Omega^nS^n$.  The only maps that are homotopy equivalences have degree $1$ and $-1$.

EDIT: In answer to the comment below from JasonDevito: For any finite CW complex $X$, $[S^1,X]$ is the same thing as $[S^0,\Omega X]$, since $\Omega$ and $\Sigma$ (reduced suspension) are adjoints.  But, based maps from $S^0$ to $Y$ is the same as $Y$ for any finite CW complex.  Thus

$$
[S^1,X]=[S^0,\Omega X]=\Omega X.
$$

Iterate this and you get

$$
[S^n,S^n]=[\Sigma S^{n-1},S^n]=[S^{n-1},\Omega S^n]=\cdots =\Omega^n S^n.
$$

Comment: I feel as though I'm being dense, but I have an intuitive way of thinking about $\Omega S^n$.  How does one think about $\Omega^n S^n$ in terms of $[S^n,S^n]?$  For example, how does a loop of loops in $S^2$ correspond to a map from $S^2$ to itself?  Is each loop coming from, say, a lattitude of $S^2$ and the north and south poles are, up to homotopy, sent to the same point (making a trivial loop?)

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Does my edit answer you question?

Comment: It does - I was being *very* dense.  I've actually *used* these facts on answers I've posted on Mathoverflow - I'm just running really low on sleep.  Sorry to be a bother!

Comment: If these are homotopy classes then isn't $\mathbb Z = \pi_n(S^n) = [S^n, S^n] =[S^0, \Omega^n S^n ] = \pi_0(\Omega^n S^n)$, with the two path components corresponding to $1$ and $-1$.